# getOrgChart font size change

Tags: jquery, orgchart

I'm using getOrgchart and trying to change color and font size in a getOrgChart so the names in the box don't get truncated.
I would also like to change page background color and box color

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet below changes the font size, box colors and background color

```js
 $("#people").getOrgChart({   
  theme: "monica",
  primaryColumns: ["name", "title"],
  gridView: true,
  dataSource: [
   { id: 1, parentId: null, name: "Amber McKenzie Field", title: "CEO", phone: "678-772-470", mail: "lemmons@jourrapide.com", adress: "Atlanta, GA 30303" },
   { id: 2, parentId: 1, name: "Ava Field", title: "Paper goods machine setter", phone: "937-912-4971", mail: "anderson@jourrapide.com" },
   { id: 3, parentId: 1, name: "Evie Johnson", title: "Employer relations representative", phone: "314-722-6164", mail: "thornton@armyspy.com"}
  ]
 });
```

```css
html, body {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
#people {width: 100%;height: 100%; } 



div.get-org-chart.get-darkred
{
  background-color: white;
}

div.get-org-chart .get-text
{
  font-size: 20px !important;
}

div.get-org-chart.get-darkred .get-oc-c .get-box
{
  fill: blue;
  stroke: darkblue;  
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//www.getorgchart.com/GetOrgChart/getorgchart/getorgchart.css">       
<script type='text/javascript' src="//www.getorgchart.com/GetOrgChart/getorgchart/getorgchart.js"></script>

<div id="people"></div>
```